# NVIDA video adapter detected as 3D controller instead of VGA controller

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kvm-virtualization, qemu

[image]I want to try PCI passthrough I'm totally new at this, so i began by following a YouTube tutorial. When it came to the part where i can see what device that I'm going to passthrough " `lscpi -nn | grep -iP 'VGA|3D|Audio` " part, i realize that my geforce 920mx is detected as 3D controller instead of as a VGA controller, but I'm pretty sure that i set 920mx as the prime profile. Is a 3D controller acceptable for PCI passthrough?

Comment: It is OK to be either a VGA or 3D controller.

Comment: can i still pass the nvdia to qemu ?, totally new at this

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia is detected as a 3D controller in case it is a discrete adapter in addition to an integrated one. That's not a problem.

It means that the output is done through the integrated controller and Nvidia is used only for acceleration.

Comment: so i just can put the integrated controller or both of them on passtrough ?

Comment: I never used PCI passthrough, but I would start with the integrated one. Dual graphics may complicate things a lot.

Comment: I would ask a specific question like "How to passtrough dual graphics" instead of asking why it is 3D.

Comment: can i make the nvidia to be the main output rather than just for acceleration ?

Comment: No, you can't. The system on laptops is designed this way.

Comment: Soo sad to hear that, well thanks, i think i should begin with the integrated one.